# Extract count of groups and groups within a word using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex to determine how many and which groups are repeated.

`Input String= $$$ 12345 aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  678 $$$ aaabbbbccc aaa-bbb-ddd aab aaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbc a000000009999999888888`

```
Expected Output = 
$$$ 
12345 
aaa  
bbb  
ccc  
ddd  
eee  
678 
$$$ 

aaa
bbbb
ccc 

aaa
bbb
ddd 

aa
b 

aaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbb
c 

a
00000000
9999999
888888
```

Please note that I have separated `aaa` from `aaaaaa` `bbbbbbbbbbbbb` and `c`for visual clarity. The actual output won't have any space or newline character between the words.

**Rules:**

**1)** There could be `n` number of words with characters among `a-zA-Z0-9$`. In above example, `$$$` and `12345` are words.

**2)** A word could have `n` groups with repeated characters.  E.g. `aaa` and `a`

**3)** What is the difference between a word and a group inside word? E.g. What is the difference between `12345` and `aab`.

**Answer:** `12345` doesn't have any repeated element. So, this stays as is without any further breakdown. However, `aab` has one repeated character `a` because of which it will be broken down into `aa` and `b`.

**4)** The output (consisting of groups) must not have any spaces or newline characters before or after the group.

I was able to separate words from each other. This was easy. I used `r[$0-9a-zA-Z]+` However, I am unsure how to separate groups inside the word. i.e.  how do I separate `a000000009999999888888` into `a` `00000000` `9999999` `888888`?

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Here's my regex101 sheet: [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/MLy38n/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If negative lookahead is supported, you might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and 2 capturing groups.

`([a-z0-9$])\1+|(?:([a-z0-9$])(?!\2))+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WMQgqO/1)

- `([a-z0-9$])\1+` Match consecutive characters by capturing a what is in the character class in group 1 followed by repeating group 1 one or more times
- `|` Or
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `([a-z0-9$])` Match what is in the character class and capture in group 2
  - `(?!\2)` Negative lookahead to assert that what follows is not group 2
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat one or more times

You did not specify any tool or language, but just an example how to get the full matches in [Php](https://3v4l.org/P1Zh1) or in [Python](http://rextester.com/DMA72296).

Comment: Thanks so much. This is an ingenious answer. Do you mind describing the effect of having a capturing group (in your solution above) enclosed within non-capturing group? Also, could you please recommend a good resource (or a book) for me to learn regex ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @watchtower The effect of `(?:([a-z0-9$])(?!\2))+` is that the non capturing group `(?:)+` is repeated one or more times. What is inside that repetition is the current match captured in a group and a negative lookahead to assert if what follows is not the character of the currently captured one. On the next repetition, the captured group will be the next match. Then you will check again if what follows is not is not the character of the currently captured one.

Comment: [RexEgg](https://www.rexegg.com/) and [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) are great resources. [This page](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-books.html#books) also refers to books and resources.